# Javascript modular design pattern - which is better: self-invoking function, or object literal approach?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

In my quest to write better, tighter, more secure code I am excited to be adopting a more modular pattern in my Javascript. However in my self-education on the subject, I am seeing there are different ways to do it. It seems that the two most common would be the self-invoking function pattern ([from this article](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/4-javascript-design-patterns-you-should-know)):

```
var HTMLChanger = (function() {
  var contents = 'contents'

  var changeHTML = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('attribute-to-change');
    element.innerHTML = contents;
  }

  return {
    callChangeHTML: function() {
      changeHTML();
      console.log(contents);
    }
  };

})();

HTMLChanger.callChangeHTML();       // Outputs: 'contents'
console.log(HTMLChanger.contents);  // undefined
```

or, [from this other article](https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/), the object literal approach pattern:

```
var s,
NewsWidget = {

  settings: {
    numArticles: 5,
    articleList: $("#article-list"),
    moreButton: $("#more-button")
  },

  init: function() {
    s = this.settings;
    this.bindUIActions();
  },

  bindUIActions: function() {
    s.moreButton.on("click", function() {
      NewsWidget.getMoreArticles(s.numArticles);
    });
  },

  getMoreArticles: function(numToGet) {
    // $.ajax or something
    // using numToGet as param
  }

};
```

And I am sure a host of others (some described in the first article) - which pattern is better, and/or more common? If I were to choose a default go-to (unless I had a specific reason to choose another pattern) which should it be, and why?

Is it perfectly acceptable to mix and match?

Comment: kinda comparing apples to oranges..

Comment: I am thinking a mix and match. That the self-invoking structure should be good for functionality that needs to run or be available on a page load, while the constructor pattern is better for for things that don't need to be available until directly called? It does seem that the self-invoking functions offer more privacy however

Comment: That's the point in using iife's, that you can have a private scope/things *(functions/variables/classes/whatever)* and expose only a public API.

Comment: IIFEs allow you much more flexibility and cover a variety of use cases so it should be the go-to pattern.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense

Comment: Note that ES2015+ has "classes", although they're largely syntactic sugar.

Comment: @DaveNewton Interesting, so do you think with the full adoption of ES6 that this will be a non-issue?

Comment: `which pattern is better` - the better one is the one that is more suited to the task you want to perform

Comment: @HolyMoly - full implementation of ES6 will **add** to the programmers arsenal - again, right tool, right job

Comment: @HolyMoly The patterns serve different purposes. JS OOP goes beyond simple data hiding provided by IIFEs. Classes are sugar over its standard prototypal inheritance and silver a different problem than simple name spacing.

Comment: @JaromandaX your right, it is more of an object literal. I should know better. I will edit

Comment: Has anyone here realized how bad the second code is? Especially for a newbie. What this little variable `s` represents, and the implications/problems that come with the way this var is used?

Comment: I personally didn't really understand why he put the `var s` on the global scope, or why he used it all when he could just call `this.settings.moreButton` since it's not like he needed to preserve the scope of `this` in his example....but other than that, why is it dangerous? What else did I miss? @Thomas

Comment: you mean other than being in danger of namespace conflict on account of being so short?

Comment: good call, didn't catch that

Comment: If he would have used `this.settings` this whole Module would have been singleton or actually static. But to me this reads more like an attempt to create instances or more precise state (because the logic is static); and it doesn't work out, due to the shared nature of the global variable `s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't say one is better than the other but i will try to make explicit the advantages of each one so you can choose which to use in your own case.

The constructor pattern creates an objects with its attributes and methods, all of them will be public. It is very easy to understand and you can still add functionality after the creation.

The self invoking pattern (aka. SEAF or IIFE) can look more complicated at the beginning but it has the advantage to have private attributes or methods so you can specify which part of the code will expose. You can also make it all private by skipping the return statement.

One amazing article that has helped me understanding JavaScript patterns is [How Good C# Habits can Encourage Bad JavaScript Habits](https://appendto.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/). Even though it says from C# to Javascript, it is suitable for anyone using JS.

As a conclusion the IIFE pattern will give you all the tools that you may want to add in a module but it does not mean that using the constructor pattern isn't more convenient in some cases where the functionality is less complex. About mixing them up, personally i dislike projects where several patterns are used for one goal. IMHO using IIFE is more robust and long term useful but for a quick & fun game object literals may be the way to go :-)

Comment: I agree on both all points. With that said, is it fair to say mixing them up is acceptable within the same app or even file? Should I, say, be using the SEAF pattern when I need things to happen on a page load or if privacy is an issue - and the constructor pattern when that is not the case?

Comment: thanks for the link!!

Comment: Thanks that is a great question, i tried answering that on my last edit!

Comment: the last edit is great, very clear. I will wait a little while and see if anyone chimes in before i mark anything though ;) thank you for your response, very helpful!

Comment: oh no, it was clear, both the first and second version, but the second edit added a little more info and you addressed the 'mixing' aspect -  but you have explained yourself clearly the whole way ;) Thanks again!!

Comment: wops, i guess we confused. the final comment was directed to a now removed comment from another person. nevermind.. and thank you!